# Mysql Update Statement with Case Not Working

Tags: mysql, sql

What am I doing wrong, I keep getting errors about syntax.

```
UPDATE common_lookup    
SET     common_lookup_column = 
CASE
  WHEN common_lookup_table = 'MEMBER' THEN
    CASE
      WHEN common_lookup_type IN ('INDIVIDUAL', 'GROUP') THEN
        common_lookup_table || '_TYPE'
      WHEN common_lookup_type LIKE '%CARD' THEN
       'CREDIT_CARD_TYPE'
    END
  ELSE
    common_lookup_table || '_TYPE'
END;
```

Comment: What is ` || '_TYPE'`?

Comment: You missing `END CASE;`. Twice.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, using the `concat()` function:

```
UPDATE common_lookup    
    SET common_lookup_column = (CASE WHEN common_lookup_table = 'MEMBER'
                                     THEN (CASE WHEN common_lookup_type IN ('INDIVIDUAL', 'GROUP')
                                                THEN concat(common_lookup_table, '_TYPE')
                                                WHEN common_lookup_type LIKE '%CARD'
                                                THEN 'CREDIT_CARD_TYPE'
                                           END)
                                     ELSE concat(common_lookup_table, '_TYPE')
                                END);
```

Assuming that you don't *intend* to have `NULL` values from the inner `case`, you can simplify this logic to:

```
UPDATE common_lookup    
    SET common_lookup_column = (CASE WHEN common_lookup_table = 'MEMBER' AND
                                          common_lookup_type LIKE '%CARD'
                                     THEN 'CREDIT_CARD_TYPE'
                                     ELSE concat(common_lookup_table, '_TYPE')
                                END);
```

The operation `||` is the string concatenation operator in several databases.